# Can we please have a link to a user's chat profile in their site (and meta) profile page?

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-page

The space below reputation and badges, on the left-hand-side of the user profile, offers enough space for a link to their chat profile.

The reason I'm asking for this is: (for example) when I am reviewing and need to communicate with the user, e.g. to explain things or clarify, I need to open a new chat room with them. For that, I apparently need to find out their chat profile, and can start a chat from that page. The current procedure for this is:

- Go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users and type in (or try having luck copy-and-pasting without accidentally clicking the link every time) their SO username
- Follow the resulting link to their chat.SO profile (bad luck if there are several users with this name, and no clear avatars – plus, the avatars are greyed out anyway if they were not active in chat; also, bad luck if they do not have a chat profile at all yet)
- Hover over the link back from their chat profile to their SO profile (“parent user”, taking note of the number behind `/users/`
- Compare *that* with their user number on their SO or meta.SO profile (e.g. from my address bar), to be *really* sure I've got the correct one

Only then can I enter a chat with them. (And to add insult to injury, writing @theirusername does not appear to ping them, as they are not in that chat yet. But apparently, creating the chat in the first place (automatically inviting them) does, so, no problem.)

So, to make this process a bit more easy/streamlined, please link from the parent profile (and possibly the meta one) to their chat profile. (This could also help on sites without their own chat site, which use the SE chat.)

Comment: I think this would be very useful. So much so, I added it to a userscript I have. When at someone's bare profile page (the one when you click on their name), you can add the "chat" hostname to it, to arrive at their chat profile. So, example.com/users/234/pickle -> chat.example.com/users/234/pickle

Comment: @AndrewBarber the numeric ID of chat users differs from those of parent users, so this is not possible client-side ☹

Comment: @mirabilos Hmmm... That's never failed for me on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mirabilos I looked at couple of randomly-selected users on the SO front page and your profiles, and their chat ID was the same as their regular ID in all cases; Andrew's method should work.

Comment: Seems like what you really want is a "Chat with this person" button. Or is there other stuff of value on the chat profile?

Comment: @jpmc26 for the specific use case I cited, that button would also work. But I can imagine the other stuff from the profile to be mildly useful, if not for me then for others, so I thought to request the generic solution.

Comment: When I go to a users' profile, I simply add `chat.` to the Stack Overflow link (aka ***chat**.stackoverflow.com/users/2422013/cybermonkey* for my chat profile). I agree that it'll be a nice feature if this was implemented all all Stack Exchange sites and not only Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't like this. It's bad enough that users can request one-on-one chats outside the scope of a single post as it is; it definitely shouldn't be that readily obvious and accessible. This will inevitably lead to more users expecting individual help sessions. Then, when you ignore them or refuse to completely debug their current situation, suddenly your answers are un-accepted, and the exact same questions are reposted until they find someone who will.

Comment: @MikeM. If that ever happens moderators would probably help with that, although that'll be increasing the burden they have. I personally think that the reason no chat link is there is to prevent abuse of the system, but then the reputation-floor for chat is 20 rep.

Comment: @bob: Great tip to `chat.`-prefix the regular SO user-profile URL. How about posting that as an answer, with the caveat that it only works on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Still not implemented, why??? unlike if they're ignoring us

Answer (score -6):

I know that this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is 7 years old, but just recently, due to the new profile design, it would be much easier to add the link by simply including it in the Profiles drop-down menu found on each profile:

[image: Image of a drop-down menu from a user's main profile, consisting 2 links; one link to the meta profile and one link to the network profile]

Comment: So, that would already include 2 chat profile links. One to SO chat, and one to SE chat? That seems... Excessive.

Comment: @Cerbrus Don't forget meta chat

Comment: @Cerbrus No, not to SE chat; that would go in your MSE profile.